# How I can create child windows in Performance Point Service in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: performancepoint, business-intelligence

I use `Performance Point Service` in'SharePoint 2013 for create BI Reports from SSAS.

I need to create some reports that have child window. Like in this picture:

[image]

Can I create a report like this? And how?